# How to pass byte[] to stored procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, arrays

I have this function auto-generated by EF that calls my stored procedure passing it a byte[]:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> IPv6Country_Get(byte[] ipBytes)
{
  var ipBytesParameter = ipBytes != null ?
      new ObjectParameter("ipBytes", ipBytes) :
      new ObjectParameter("ipBytes", typeof(byte[]));

  return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("IPv6Country_Get", ipBytesParameter);
}
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[IPv6Country_Get]
(
    @ipBytes varbinary
)
AS
    SELECT
        [countrySHORT] AS Country
    FROM
        [IPv6Country]
    WHERE
        @ipBytes >= [ipFROM] AND
        @ipBytes <= [ipTO]

RETURN 0
```

When the EF function is called the stored procedure gets only the first byte of the array in @ipBytes. What do I need to change so it receives the full byte[]?

Comment: you need to give the varbinary a size greater than or equal to the length of your parameter..  `@ipBytes varbinary(max)` for example.  if no length is given the default length is 1 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add lenght of varbinary

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[IPv6Country_Get]
(
    @ipBytes varbinary(max)
)
```